# images repeating cells when scrolled in tableview

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

images are not showing properly in tableview , I have two Json Api (Primary/high) school. I can append the Both Json api Data and display into tableview,
tableview working fine it's showing both(primary/high) school data. when I can scroll the tableview images are jumping and images loading very slow in image view at tableview.

Before scrolling tableview its showing like this

[image]

[image]

After scrolling the tableview it's shows like this

after scrolling images are jumping,

[image]

this is the code

```
     var kidsdata = [KidDetails]()

    func getprimarydata(_firsturl: String,firstid:String,updatedate:String)
    {


                                        if errorCode == "0" {

                                      if let kid_list = jsonData["students"] as? NSArray {

                                      self.kidsdata.removeAll()

                                      for i in 0 ..< kid_list.count {

                                      if let kid = kid_list[i] as? NSDictionary {


                                      let imageURL = url+"/images/" + String(describing: kid["photo"]!)

                                      self.kidsdata.append(KidDetails(
                                                            name:kid["name"] as? String,
                                                            photo : (imageURL),
                                                            standard: ((kid["standard"] as? String)! +  "std" + " " + (kid["section"] as? String)! + " section ")
                                                            ))}}}}
 }


      func gethighdata(_secondurl:String ,secondid:String,updatedate:String)
        {
         if errorCode == "0" {

                                if let kid_list = jsonData["students"] as? NSArray {
                                    for i in 0 ..< kid_list.count {


                                        if let kid = kid_list[i] as? NSDictionary {

                                            let imageURL = url+"/images/" + String(describing: kid["photo"]!)

                                            self.kidsdata.append(KidDetails(
                                                name:kid["name"] as? String,
                                                photo : (imageURL),

                                    standard: ((kid["standard"] as? String)! + "th" + " " + (kid["section"] as? String)! + " section ")
                                                )
                                            )
                                        }
                                    }


                                self.do_table_refresh()
                            }
                            }
    }


        func do_table_refresh()
        {

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

                self.TableView.reloadData()

                return
            })

        }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
          let cell =
                tableView.dequeueReusableCell(
                    withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! DataTableViewCell
            cell.selectionStyle = .none

            cell.ProfileImage?.image = nil

            let row = (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row


            let kid = kidsdata[row] as KidDetails

            cell.NameLabel.text = kid.name

            cell.ProfileImage.image = UIImage(named: "profile_pic")

            cell.ProfileImage.downloadImageFrom(link:kid.photo!, contentMode: UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill)
            cell.ClassNameLabel.text = kid.standard
           return cell
        }
```

where I did mistake pls help me....!

Comment: in your tableViewCell Class you need to reset the image in the function `prepareForReuse`. This will be called every time a cell will be reused and is the fiest point, where you can remove the image. The function is implemented in UITableViewCell and you have to override it

Comment: ah and your downloading an image, is this function running the download in a background thread and is putting the image in the main thread?

Comment: And does it proof if the cell, is still the cell that requested the photo? :)

Comment: @BjörnRo images are dowloaded from background thread am assing to main thread

Comment: this is great. So the image will currently not removed when setting `cell.ProfileImage?.image = nil` . Maybe the rest would happen in the prepareForReues funcw

Comment: func prepareForReuse(){
            
            cell.ProfileImage?.image = nil
        }
        I can try inside cellForRowAt same problem repeating

Comment: so you added this func in your DataTableViewCell and overrid the main one?

Comment: what about the image that your setting as well? the ‚profile_pic‘ Do you see this one?

Comment: I can removed cell.ProfileImage?.image = nil and  cell.ProfileImage.image = UIImage(named: "profile_pic") no use

Comment: first cell and last images are shuffling

Comment: can you post the Class of the cell?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153503/discussion-between-naga-and-bjorn-ro).

Comment: I can try all ways but am not getting wer I did mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AlamofireImage handles this very well. https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage

```
import AlamofireImage

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
              let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! DataTableViewCell
                cell.selectionStyle = .none

                let kid = kidsdata[indexPath.row] as KidDetails


                cell.NameLabel.text = kid.name
                cell.ClassNameLabel.text = kid.standard

                // assuming cell.ProfileImage is a UIImageView
                cell.ProfileImage.image = nil

                let frame = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
                let filter = AspectScaledToFillSizeWithRoundedCornersFilter(size: frame, radius: 5.0)

                cell.ProfileImage.af_setImage(withURL: urlToImage, placeholderImage: nil, filter: filter,
                                      imageTransition: .crossDissolve(0.3), runImageTransitionIfCached: false)

               return cell
    }
```

Comment: am using tableview in tab bar controller when the application launched first time tableview is not scrolling and not able to access tabbar items, after rerun app it's working fine, how to over com this problem

Comment: tableview Scrolling is working after my project clean and re run the app

Comment: after am try to add AlamofireImage  app is crashing

Comment: because of the     let row = (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row and kidsdata.count does not matching count

Comment: You probably should be calling tableView.reloadData() somewhere where you aren't right now.

Answer (score 0):

All we need to do is use the `prepareForReuse()` function. As discussed in [this](https://medium.com/ios-seminar/why-we-use-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier-ce7fd97cde8e) medium article, This function is called before cell reuse, letting you cancel current requests and perform a reset.

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()

    ProfileImage.image = nil
}
```